# Which are the source of java to fill system properties

Tags: java, system-properties

Through [System.getProperty(String key)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)) you can get the value of some java system properties, however my question is about how java fill these values, more exactly where is the source of this information. I'm looking in some places like [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) but I didn't found an answer.

My problem is that I'm trying to test some behaviours of my code, and I want to change the system property for `os.name` value outside of java (I know that I can set the value with [`System.setProperty(String key, String value)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) however I want to do it outside), so anybody knows what I've to change in order to get the new value through `System.getProperty('os.name')`?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to run `java -Dos.name="Moon OS"` ? (not sure if you can change non-custom properties that way)

Comment: Thanks guys, I know that this can be achieved with `-Dos.name` however I was looking for a different way to do so outside java, sorry if this was not really clear in my question.

Comment: what do you mean? It is using the command line arguments of the JVM so it is outside java... Unless you meant changing your actual OS in a way that the JVM will automatically feed a different value for `os.name`? In that case the answer will probably vary across OSes...

Comment: @assylias as you said: `I mean changing my actual OS in a way that the JVM will automatically feed a different value for os.name`, I apologize if this it's not really clear in my question, sorry `:(`. However as @ElliottFirsch notes in his answer there is no "easy" way to do so, isn't it?. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you should modify the built-in [System Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html), the linked Java Tutorial says (in part)

> The `System` class maintains a `Properties` object that describes the configuration of the current working environment.

and

> **Warning:** Changing system properties is potentially dangerous and should be done with discretion. Many system properties are not reread after start-up and are there for informational purposes. Changing some properties may have unexpected side-effects.

finally

> To modify the existing set of system properties, use `System.setProperties`. This method takes a `Properties` object that has been initialized to contain the properties to be set.

Comment: yes, I know it's potentially dangerous but I only want to do some tests, and as I comment in my answer  I can use `setProperty` however I was looking for a different way and as you said seems that there is no option (except using `-Dos.name` however this is not the way I was looking for). Thanks.

Comment: Use System.setProperties not setProperty.

Comment: I can use both no? `setProperty(String key, String value)`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String) and `setProperties(Properties props)`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperties(java.util.Properties). However setProperty to set only one variable looks more convenient to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a VM argument as

```
-Dos.name="Ubuntu 10.1"
```

If you're running Eclipse, you can specify the value through Run > Run configurations... Select your program under, say, Java Application and the providing the value in the Arguments tab.

Comment: Yes, I did before posting. In Eclipse though.

Answer (score 0):

You can run java it with the option `-Dos.name="XXX"` so `System.getProperty('os.name')` will return 'XXX'.