# How to determine the Operating System using Java?

Tags: java, operating-system

I want to find out the OS in a java program so that I can load the correct native library. I know that using `System.getProperty("os.name")` is an option, but I would prefer not to use it because it can be set by anyone in a code base by using `System.setProperty("os.name", "foo")`.

Comment: Show [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28047817/438154) to your engineers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to be sure to load the correct JNI lib from the Java runtime is to try to load any of them with System.loadLibrary() and catch exceptions, until one native library is loaded correctly. The other ways to find the underlying OS are only heuristic tools.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `System.getProperty("os.name")` because I don't think their is another way to do it, and don't worry about `setProperty` because if you think about it, no one will set it to `foo` or `bar` or something like that.